# Streaming recorded audio from browser to PHP Server

Tags: php, html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I would like to streaming audio from browser and send to PHP Server. Server will receive audio data and save to file.

I found BinaryJS can streaming binary data but it only works for NodeJS. 
For PHP, I found that Ratchet PHP can do socket comnunication but it can't stream binary data.

How can I stream binary data to PHP Server ? Thanks.

Comment: does not make sense to me, what's the source of the audio?

Comment: @Dagon It's tagged with HTML5 audio, so probably the Web Audio API.

Comment: @DavidTran There are other Web Socket libraries for PHP, and some support binary data:  https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket

Comment: I must really catch up with html5 some time - thanks @Brad

Comment: @Dagon Check this out:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Thanks @Brad, this library is great. In the example, I can transfer the whole file succesful. I wonder if I can just send chunk of file util finish?

Comment: @DavidTran You can, depending on how you're getting that data to begin with.  I had assumed you were using the Web Audio API where it was likely that your data was in chunks already.  Can you clarify your question with information on your data source?

Comment: source of audio from microphone. I use html5 audio recorder to record audio and send to server.